Why can I read a text file on pc, but not android
I'm making a wordle clone, and I have a list of words in a .txt file all seperated by a newLine. When I read the lines of the text file, something goes wrong on mobile.
When I do a File.ReadAllLines(path) on pc, it works fine and I am able to get a random word for the game. However, when I build the game and install it on my android, it doesn't pick a word and I think it just quits the script. I have tried to get logcat to work for debugging on my phone but it doesn't work for me.
Here is the code seperated from everything:

void Start()
    {
        // all target words
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "possibleWordsList.txt");

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            possibleWordsList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                possibleWordsList.Add(line);
            }   
        }

        targetWord = possibleWordsList[(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1000))];
        // i use UnityEngine.Random as there was a conflict above with system.IO
    }


Check your permissions in android manifest file

The Application.dataPath directly points to the APK on Android. If you wish to just include a fixed file, it's probably better to put it in a Resources folder and load it through something like Resources.Load().
If you wish to changes files over time, you might want to look into Application.persistentDataPath instead.
